# How to set up listener for dynamic buttons of same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I am new to JavaScript and **knockout.js**. My problem is the following:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: myOuterArray">
    <li>
        [...]    
        <table>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: a.myInnerArray">
                [...]
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button class="mybutton" data-bind="">Add items to myInnerArray</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I iterate over myOuterArray, whose items (objects of type a) have got inner arrays, too. After representing the myInnerArrays items I add a button to every myOuterArray item. The button opens a jQuery UI dialog with a select list. Now, this button should add stuff from dialog to the corresponding myInnerArray. Maybe I'm a little slow on the uptake today, but I really do not know how to set up the button listener for .mybutton in my viewmodel.
All fields are observable, if this matters.

Comment: Sorry, my fault! I was a blockhead. Thought, I can not use the data-bind attribute because I needed a jQuery UI Listener. Please delete/forget this question! Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Would it not work to simply use the click binding on your button?

```
<button class="mybutton" data-bind="click: handlerMethod">Add items to myInnerArray</button>
```

I imagine the handler would be in the same viewModel as your `myOuterArray` observable, so the bind would more likely be `click: $parent.handlerMethod`

Within this method you can take in a data parameter, which would be the current myOuterArray item according to your HTML structure.

```
    handlerMethod: function(currentOuterArrayItem, event) {
            //do stuff
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The context of the button is the current element of the myOuterArray, so if type A as a function called typeAFoo it should look like

```
data-bind="click: typeAFoo"
```

Your question does not not involve jQuery UI so remove that tag, or edit question if you really have a question about ko with jQuery UI